# Overwrite cells in CSV, if name matches in column A

Tags: powershell, csv

I am compiling a Powershell script to import accounts from a CSV file, ask users a few questions and overwrite the existing data back into the CSV file.

The script works great except when it gets to the Export-CSV, which either appends the data or overwrites the entire file.

Is there a way to overwrite cells adjacent to a matched name in column A and add new lines if the account is new?

```
$accountName = Read-Host "What is the account name?"

$alldata = Import-Csv "C:\Users\$logontr\Desktop\NewAccounts\TestOutput0.csv"
$data = $alldata | Where-Object { $_."Account" -eq $accountName }

$serialNumber = Read-Host "Confirm Serial Number"

if ($data -ne $null) {
  # re-export the data, excluding the account
  $alldata | Where-Object { $_."Account" -ne $accountName } | Export-Csv C:\Users\$logontr\Desktop\NewAccounts\TestOutput0.csv -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation -Encoding ASCII
}

[pscustomobject]@{
  Account = $accountName
  Serial = $serialNumber
  SoftwareAssurance = $date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
  Validated = Get-Date -Format d
  DataCollection = $DCRun
  DataCollectionDate = $DCRunDate
} | Export-Csv C:\Users\$logontr\Desktop\NewAccounts\TestOutput0.csv -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation -Encoding ASCII
```

Thanks

Comment: Updated the code to show everything which might help

Comment: It is more useful to provide a minimal example.

Comment: Why do you have a potential data export twice?, and why do you export what you just imported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have checks in place to make sure the user actually completes the process? This solution will work but needs some error checking so you don't end up removing an account when a user cancels half-way through.

```
$alldata = Import-CSV "C:\Users\$logontr\Desktop\NewAccounts\TestOutput0.csv"
$data =  $alldata | Where-Object { $_."Account" -eq $accountName }

# Code that gets information from user goes here.

if($data -ne $null){
    # re-export the data, excluding the account
    # edited to add -Force flag
    $alldata | Where-Object { $_."Account" -ne $accountName } | Export-csv C:\Users\$logontr\Desktop\NewAccounts\TestOutput0.csv -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation -Encoding ASCII -Force
}

# use existing append code
[pscustomobject]@{
Account = $accountName
Serial = $serialNumber
SoftwareAssurance = $date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
Validated = Get-Date -Format d
DataCollection = $DCRun
DataCollectionDate = $DCRunDate
} | Export-csv C:\Users\$logontr\Desktop\NewAccounts\TestOutput0.csv -Append -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation -Encoding ASCII

# if the user does not complete the task, re-export the csv
# $alldata | Export-csv C:\Users\$logontr\Desktop\NewAccounts\TestOutput0.csv -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation -Encoding ASCII
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response, I don't have any checks in place yet...

The user can close the window at any point, assuming that's what you mean?

Comment: Yep, that is what I mean. Does the user click an "Update" button or something like that to apply the change?

Comment: Basically, you need to make sure the `if` loop executes after you are sure that you have the information required to update the file. In this case the re-export that is at the bottom is not required.

Comment: No, they just run the script and input the data on the terminal which then sets the variables and it outputs at the end. Please forgive me if this doesn't make sense, or is the wrong way to do it as I am very new to PS.

Comment: I just tried with your code and it didn't quite have the effect that I was looking for, although this is most likely my mistake. It says that the CSV already exists. Should the if($data -ne $null) be at the start of the script, before the user input?

Comment: Apologies for the late response. It's correct to have that part AFTER the user input to ensure you have the required information to go ahead.I have edited my answer to clarify this, and to add a `-Force` flag to the $alldata export.